# Hide Status Bar of a VC embedded in Navigation Controller in iPhoneX

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I want to hide status bar of a particular ViewController which is presented in a navigation Controller. I have tried like this:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
 }
```

And in `viewWillAppear`

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

I have also set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in project's plist but nothing is working in iPhoneX. The above way is working in notchless devices. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

for the `prefersStatusBarHidden` to be reflected